# Sessions in BigQuery

Tags: session, google-bigquery

we have the data model and we are consulting with BigQuery from the console and from ODBC but I can not find the way to calculate the number of Sessions and the duration of them. Could you help me to get those KPIs? Thank you so much!

Our data schema:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=es&ref_topic=7029512&authuser=0

Comment: Please post the schema in your question, do not use links.

Comment: Indeed there's no field for the session in the firebase schema. I wonder how would you define a session? In GA I think the session is defined as a period of 30 minutes between one action and the other. In firebase maybe this could be a period of 30 minutes between `event_dim.timestamp_micros` for each event but still not sure how you want it to be defined.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546815/how-to-calculate-session-and-session-duration-in-firebase-analytics-raw-data