# How to calculate session length and no of sessions in Firebase raw data?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have linked Firebase project with BigQuery. How to calculate session length and number of sessions from the data. Is there any column or event_name similar to **'.session_start / .session_stop '** which stores the session details like in AWS Pinpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42548974/10161872), seems it will be useful to your question. As well, the BigQuery export [schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) and the following query [samples](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9037342?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) will be useful as start point to deploy queries over the exported Firebase Analytics data.

(I don't have reputation to add this as a comment)