# How to define session metric in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm setting up Firebase for a mobile app. I'm finding conflicting information on Firebase's definition of a session on Google documentation as well as stackoverflow itself.

Firebase documentation and stackoverflow state that I should use "SetMinimumSessionDuration" to define the metric—however this parameter has recently been marked as **Depracated** (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/deprecated/deprecated).

It is mentioned that "a session is initiated when an app is opened in the foreground" (see https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9191807?hl=en), but I am not confident that this webpage has been published recently and is still valid.

Does anybody have solid info on how Firebase sets this metric?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to actually achieve? Do you want to know what is session and how it works or how to set session duration?

Comment: How to set a session duration (if there's not definition that's set in stone!)

Comment: I would really recommend to not think in terms of "session" in context of Firebase. It is very event-driven, so I would advise to think about what you want to achieve in terms of *events*.

Answer (score 0):

Before Jan 2019 ([Analytics version 16.3.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_january_31_2019)), the default value for minimum session duration was 10 seconds. The `session_start` event was triggered if there was no current session, and the app was in the foreground for more than 10 seconds.

After Jan 2019, it was changed so that the `session_start` event is triggered as soon as the app is foregrounded. The `SetMinimumSessionDuration` parameter is now deprecated and can no longer be changed. See [The Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html).

However, when you run a SQL query in BigQuery, you should be able to specify a minimum duration of a session for the purpose of analysis. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546815/how-to-calculate-session-and-session-duration-in-firebase-analytics-raw-data) to get you started with such queries.

You can also still change the `setSessionTimeoutDuration` [parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-void-setsessiontimeoutduration-long-milliseconds) to control the duration of inactivity that terminates the current session (default: 30 minutes).