# BigQuery - get user sessions from a very large events table

Tags: google-bigquery

Having an extremely large events table in BigQuery:

```
uid   |event_time             |
------+-----------------------+
1     |2020-03-01 14:43:01.380|
------+-----------------------+
1     |2020-03-01 14:53:01.320|
------+-----------------------+
2     |2020-03-01 15:03:01.180|
...
```

I'm trying to count the number of sessions based on the time passed since the last event, if more then 10 minutes passed I consider it to be a new event.

I've written the following query:

```
with sessions as(
select uid ,event_time, 
lag(event_time ,1) over (PARTITION BY uid  ORDER BY event_time) previous_event_time
FROM `af-raw-data.prodv1.inapps_android_regular`             
WHERE _PARTITIONDATE BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-02'
limit 1000
)
select *, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(event_time),TIMESTAMP(previous_event_time),MINUTE)  minuets_passed,
case(previous_event_time is null 
or 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(event_time),TIMESTAMP(previous_event_time),MINUTE) > 5)
when true then 1 else 0 end is_new_session from sessions
```

It works fine and produce the expected output, however it uses a limit of 1000 records, when I try to run it on a day of data BigQuery crashes.

I'm looking for other way to count the number of 10 minuets sessions per user.

Comment: If you remove the limit, what error do you get? Also, how much time it takes to crash?

Comment: I think I answered this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546815/how-to-calculate-session-and-session-duration-in-firebase-analytics-raw-data. If not, please add more information, and we can re-open this one.